# SSL connection error - Connection reset by peer - On Homestead machine

Tags: laravel, ssl, homestead

We have an application using reCAPTCHA, the application works without problems on the production environment, but on mine new development homestead machine, I get the following error:

```
file_get_contents(): SSL: Connection reset by peer
```

I also have troubles using composer, there I get the following error:

```
[ErrorException]
zlib_decode(): data error
```

I think both errors are related to SSL.

Do I miss something, do I have to configure the CACERTS by hand?

Comment: Did you register reCaptcha to use with your homestead machine? Your queries could have been blocked by Google.

Comment: Yes, I have added the local testing domain. The CAPTCHA is displayed correct.

Comment: Can you clarify if registering your domain solved the problem? If so, please, answer your own question below.

Comment: No it doesn't, the error occurs when the form is submitted, including the CAPTCHA. I don't think it's direct related to the reCAPTCHA, I think ist a SSL/PHP config problem on Homestead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to VirtualBox as mentioned [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7946).

After a downgrade of OSX (Sierra 10.12.1) VirtualBox from 5.1.8 to 5.1.6, the problem was solved.